How to adjust parent anchors so that they don't touch
I want to make my tree look like the default tree in the forest documentation, like below:
As you can see, there is some spacing between the edges, and their endpoints are not connected to each other.
However, I am not able to replicate this in my code:
\begin{forest} for tree={
    s sep=1cm, 
    }
    [
        $(p \land (\lnot q))$
        [
            $p$, s sep=1cm, 
        ]
        [
            $(\lnot q)$
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}

This is the graph I'm getting, where the parent anchors are all touching each other.
How do you make it not touch? Thanks in advance!


Welcome! This is due to code you've not shown. Just to say that for logical tableaux, you usually would want them to touch but, if you don't, forest's defaults don't touch. I assume you have set something earlier which changes this. For example, perhaps you've loaded a library.

Ohh, I have found the issue. I was using \usepackage[linguistics]{forest} instead of \usepackage{forest}. Haha oops, thanks for the help!

That'll do it ;). As you see, that was my guess. There are other ways, but that seemed most likely.

By default, the parent anchors don't touch. For example,
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} for tree={
  s sep'=1cm, 
  math content,
  }
  [(p \land (\lnot q)
    [p
    ]
    [(\lnot q)
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

produces

Apologies for the poor quality images. Okular on X has a bug right now and I'm not very good with convert.
If, however, you change
\usepackage{forest}

to
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

you obtain

In general, this is what you want in a logical tableau. For example, prooftrees would produce the following by default,

But you can override this in the tableau's preamble. For example,
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[tableau]{prooftrees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tableau}{%
  for tree={%
    s sep'=1cm,
    not line numbering,
    parent anchor=,
  }, 
  }
  [(p \land (\lnot q)
    [p
    ]
    [(\lnot q)
    ]
  ]
\end{tableau}
\end{document}

produces

